# анимация по клику на javascript, после выполнения другой части скрипта

Tags: javascript

есть скрипт, который при клике кнопки close запускает анимацию на CSS и прячет на основном элементе все остальные блоки:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('close').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('call').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('central').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('close').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('X').style.animation = 'close 1s linear forwards';
    document.getElementById('X').setAttribute('closed', 1);}

document.getElementById('X').onclick = function() { 
    if(document.getElementById('X').getAttribute('closed')) return; 
    document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('call').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('central').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('close').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('X').style.animation = 'open 1s linear forwards';}
```

второй блок анимации должен запускать вторую анимацию при клике уже не по кнопке, а по основному элементу nav (X), чего не происходит. Помогите решить проблему новичку или объясните как сделать. Интересует только javascript, так как его изучаю.

Вот html:

```
<nav id="X">
        <a href="#callback" id="call"></a>
        <menu>
            <div id="menu">
                <a href="" class="menu"></a>
                <a href="" class="menu"></a>
            </div>
        </menu>
        <div id="central"></div>
        <a href="#X" id="close"></a>
</nav>
```

```js
document.getElementById('close').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('call').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('central').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('close').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('X').style.animation = 'close 1s linear forwards';
  document.getElementById('X').setAttribute('closed', 1);
}

document.getElementById('X').onclick = function() {
  if (document.getElementById('X').getAttribute('closed')) return;
  document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('call').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('central').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('close').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('X').style.animation = 'open 1s linear forwards';
}
```

```html
<nav id="X">X
  <a href="#callback" id="call">Call</a>
  <menu>
    <div id="menu">
      <a href="" class="menu">Test 1</a>
      <a href="" class="menu">Test 2</a>
    </div>
  </menu>
  <div id="central">Central</div>
  <a href="#X" id="close">Close</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('close').onclick = function(e) {
  ...
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Aтрибут `closed` элемента `Х` - его же надо в какой-то момент убрать?

---

Вы в обработчике клика на элементе `Х` проверяете наличие атрибута и сразу выходите, если он есть. Атрибут надо в какой-то момент убрать, чтобы остальной код в обработчике выполнился.

Comment: работает, правда возникла проблема, что вторая анимация срабатывает при нулевом состоянии если щелкнуть на элемент X, чего не должно быть

Comment: как отключить выполнение при 0 состоянии

Comment: @Юрий `if (document.getElementById('X').getAttribute('closed') == "0")`